# What's with the "Stack Egg" icon on the main page?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro

I started noticing a "Stack Egg" pic on the main site on the right side. What's this about?

Comment: Did you try clicking it?  (I imagine it will be gone in another 24 hours or so.)

Answer (score 3):

[Happy April Fools' Day!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252367/stackegg-what-is-this-thing-called-fun)

StackEgg is basically a little game where you have to improve the site, taking it from private beta, to public beta, to graduation, to winning the internet.

Come on, let's go win the internet!

Comment: No. It's to celebrate 11 Nissan: the traditional Jewish holiday of egg-based digital minigames. (In the Diaspora this is celebrated on 12 Nissan as well.)

Comment: @DoubleAA _betza [shenol'dah](http://chabad.org/1820894)_.